# Match pattern, do calculation and print only 3 or 4 floating values max

Tags: text-processing, awk

I would like to convert below to GB and print only 3 floating values

```
v  copvol2      fsgen        ENABLED  204800   -        ACTIVE   -       -
v  copvol3      fsgen        ENABLED  204800   -        ACTIVE   -       -
v  copvol4      fsgen        ENABLED  204800   -        ACTIVE   -       -
v  copvol5      fsgen        ENABLED  204800   -        ACTIVE   -       -
v  copvol6      fsgen        ENABLED  204800   -        ACTIVE   -       -
```

Currently I'm using `nawk '/^v/{print $2,$5/2048/1024}'` and output is:

```
copvol2 0.0976562
copvol3 0.0976562
copvol4 0.0976562
copvol5 0.0976562
copvol6 0.0976562
```

but I would like to receive output as below:

```
copvol2 0.0976
copvol3 0.0976
copvol4 0.0976
copvol5 0.0976
copvol6 0.0976
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `printf` to print custom-formatted records / fields / variables:

```
nawk '/^v/{printf "%s %.4f\n", $2, $5/2048/1024}'
```